# C pipe: Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, fork, producer-consumer

I have the simple producer consumer program in C try to solve it with fork 
I get error exactly when producer tries to write on pipe:
I have wrote another program with the same logic but this one does not give me any clue to know why?

**Producer failed to write item on pipe: Bad file descriptor**

Anyone have idea why I get this error?
Thanks

```
#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1
int mutex = 1, full = 0, empty = BUFFER_SIZE, x = 0;

void consumer();

void producer();

int wait_(int);

int signal_(int);

int pipefd[2];

int main() {
    printf("Starting producer-consumer problem!\n");
    //We intend to run the producer in parent process and the consumer in the child process
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {       /* An error has occurred. */
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "The call to pipe() has failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(pipefd); j++) {
        if (pipe(&pipefd[j]) < 0) { //Initialize each pipe appropriately
            perror("Error in making pipe...");
        }
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("**********Error in creating fork()!**************\n");
        exit(STDERR_FILENO);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        consumer();//We intend to run the consumer in child
    } else {
        producer();//We intend to run the producer in parent
    }
    return 0;
}

int wait_(int s) {
    return (--s);
}

int signal_(int s) {
    return (++s);
}

void producer() {
    printf("Starting Producer\n");
    //while (1) {
    //sleep(1);
    if (close(pipefd[READ]) != 0) {
        perror("Error in closing reading pipe");
    }
    if (write(pipefd[WRITE], &full, 1) < 0) {
        perror("Producer failed to write item on pipe");
    }
    if ((mutex == 1) && (empty != 0)) {
        mutex = wait_(mutex);
        full = signal_(full);
        empty = wait_(empty);
        x++;
        printf("Producer produces the item %d\n", x);
        mutex = signal_(mutex);
    }
    if (close(pipefd[WRITE]) != 0) {
        perror("Error in closing writing pipe");
    }
    //}
}

void consumer() {
    printf("Starting Consumer\n");
    //while (1) {
    //sleep(1);
    int status = 0;
    wait(&status);              /* wait for all children to return back the result */
    if (close(pipefd[WRITE]) != 0) {
        perror("Error in closing reading pipe");
    }
    if (read(pipefd[READ], &full, 1) > 0) {
        printf("Consumer\t%d\n", full);
    }
    if ((mutex == 1) && (full != 0)) {
        mutex = wait_(mutex);
        full = wait_(full);
        empty = signal_(empty);
        printf("Consumer consumes item %d\n", x);
        x--;
        mutex = signal_(mutex);
    }
    if (close(pipefd[READ]) != 0) {
        perror("Error in closing reading pipe");
    }
    //}
}
```

Comment: Where are `READ` and `WRITE` defined?

Comment: What's REAd & WRITE value ? Is it 0 & 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size *in bytes*. So on a typical system where an `int` is four bytes, `sizeof(pipefd)` would result in the value `8`. Which is not the correct number of elements for your loop.

Also, `pipe(&pipefd[j])` is not correct either. The two pipes in `pipefd` are *already* initialized "appropriately". There's no need for any more initialization. Especially since in both this and the previous case you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Is it enough to call pipe(pipefd) for initialization?

Comment: @Metao Yes that's enough.

Comment: Thank you again. Is it mandatory to close the write descriptor of pipe? How to do it in while iterator and to make sure we don't close it twice?

Comment: @Metao In the child where you only read, it's customary to close the write-end. And the opposite in the other child.